# Git freezes computer on push/pull/fetch

Tags: git

It doesn't matter what repo, as soon as Git tries to do anything over the network it freezes my computer. Also, as soon as the computer freezes the syslog starts to fill with '^@'.

Doesn't matter if it's BitBucket, GitHub, or GitLab -- all of them have the same result.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, Linux 3.13.0-85-generic. Git version 2.8.1, installed via apt-get.

Git config settings:

```
push.default=matching
pull.rebase=true
sendpack.sideband=false
```

Comment: Are you able to upload and download files by other means?  It sounds like a problem with the network card.

Comment: Yeah, I can browse, upload/download  just fine -- I can use scp without any issues.